# Access Static define table property

Tags: php, oop

I'm really bad at OOP and I can't work out this inherited code I've been given.

This is part of the generic Model class;

```
abstract class Model
{  
  protected static $_tableName  = false;
  protected static $_itemName   = false;

  public static function tableName()
  {
    return static::$_tableName;
  }

  public static function itemName()
  {
    return static::$_itemName;
  }
```

How do I set the tablename in the Class that **I have created**???;

```
class Payments extends Model {

  //public $_tableName;  

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->$_tableName  = 'payments'; //line 13
  }

}
```

I get an error `Undefined variable: _tableName in /var/www/html/lib/Local/Models/Payments.php on line 13` when I don't set it as a parameter. and an error `Cannot redeclare static XXX\Model::$_tableName` when I do.

***UPDATE***

When I try to use the `find` method with this abstract Model, it's not setting the tableName;

```
public static function find($idOrWhere = false, $params = array(), $limit = false)
{
    $sql    = "SELECT * FROM " . static::tableName();
```

I don't know how to set that now. It just ignores what I have put in my class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the `$` when accessing a class property:

```
class Payments extends Model 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->_tableName  = 'payments';
    }
}
```

Indeed this is irritating, but that's the way php syntax works.

Comment: Thanks. Still can't figure out how to use it in one of his methods though. Can you take a look at my update?

Comment: OK, things are different if you declare the methods as "static", since without an actual object you obviously cannot use `$this` inside the methods. That will actually raise an error. But the issue already is before: it simply does not make sense to set table name inside the constructor then, since the constructor is executed when an object is created. When you create an object and use the constructor to store the table name inside that object, then the methods should _not_ be static, since then they do _not_ refer to that object! My advice: use an object, do not declare the methods as static.

Answer (score 0):

With `static` class you need to use the `self` keyword to initialize property in class:

```
class Foo {
  static $bar;
}
Foo::$bar = array(…);
```

or

```
class Foo {
  private static $bar;
  static function init()
  {
    self::$bar = array(…);
  }
}
Foo::init();
```